# Click rel link javascript

Tags: javascript

I have link like that:

```
<a name="sublink" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 250, y: 300}}" class="modal acymailing_togglemodule" id="acymailing_togglemodule_formAcymailing45441" href="/index.php/component/acymailing/sub/display/formid-153/tmpl-component">Subscribe!</a>
```

ID is changing an every time. I would like to automatically click this link using JavaScript. When you click manualy on the link, there is the effect - hide page transparency colour and show window. But when I use:

```
document.getElementsByName('sublink').click();
```

its only normal showing linked page.

Can you help me? I think it should be in JQuery...

You can see: http://www.fxschool.pl/index.php/forex/sublink

This orange link "Kliknij aby subskrybowac.

Comment: There are bunch of libraries loaded already. You must first see which of those is responsible to handle the click and show the custom dialog, then use manual code to trigger the event yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName()` returns a node list. You need to index it to get a single element to click:

```
document.getElementsByName('sublink')[0].click();
```

Comment: Yhx! But still its not effect as i wish.